# Arduino UNO doesn't produce expected square waveform

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to produce quick square waveform for testing purposes. If I will use this code:

```
void setup()
{
 pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() 
{
 bitSet(PORTD, 2);
 bitClear(PORTD, 2);
}
```

I will get expected pulses but I also will get these 6.25 us dips in waveform roughly every 1 ms.

I use latest Arduino 1.6.9 environment.

Whole loop cycle take 1 us which mean 16 instructions (62.5 ns per instruction). So I will get 125 ns high and rest of the time low signal.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Same results if I use asm sbi and sci instead of macros bitSet/bitClear.

Thank you!

[image: Oscilloscope waveform - 62.5 us detail]

/*

So after yours advices and little bit further searching I came up with solution to produce clean square waveform. It make 2.66 Mhz and it's probably fastest what you can get:

```
void setup()
{
 pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
 noInterrupts();   
}

void loop() 
{
 while(true)
 {
 bitSet(PORTD, 2);
 bitClear(PORTD, 2);
 }
}
```

Comment: On the Uno, the Timer 0 overflow interrupt kicks in every 2014 µs. This is probably the glitch you are seeing. If you want to avoid it, do not use Arduino core, just plain avr-libc.

Comment: Or disable interrupts.

Comment: “_Whole loop cycle take 1 us which mean 16 instructions_”. There are actually only 6 instructions. Two of them take 4 cycles each (call and ret), the others take 2 cycles each (sbi, cbi, sbiw and breq).

Comment: Yes. I should have write "cycles" instead instructions.

Comment: The fastest you can get is 8 MHz: take the “Use a hardware timer” code I posted and change the OCR2x registers to `OCR2A = 1; OCR2B = 0;`.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Wow! Awesome! Your knowledge about Arduino amazes me! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I explained in my comment, the reason for this glitch is the Timer 0
overflow interrupt kicking in every 1024 µs. This interrupt is used
by the Arduino core library for timekeeping. It is the basis of
`millis()`, `micros()` and `delay()`. The interrupt is [enabled by the
`init()` function in
wiring.c](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring.c#L279).
There are several approaches to avoid that:

### Avoid the Arduino core initialization

This may be overkill, but since it seems you are already familiar with
directly accessing the IO ports of the ATmega chip, it may well suit
you. You can use the Arduino IDE without the Arduino core initialization
simply by defining your own `main()`:

```cpp
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void)
{
    DDRD |= _BV(PD2);        // PD2 as output
    for (;;) {
        PORTD |= _BV(PD2);   // PD2 high
        PORTD &= ~_BV(PD2);  // PD2 low
        _delay_us(0.625);    // 10 CPU cycles, loop time = 16 cycles
    }
}
```

Notice the extra delay: without it, the loop would complete in 6 CPU
cycles (2 per port access, 2 more to loop back). Not doing the Arduino
core initialization means you have no timekeeping and no `analogRead()`
or `analogWrite()`. Other Arduino functions should work normally but
some, like `Serial.begin()` will bring their own interrupts.

### Disable interrupts

As suggested by Majenko, this may be the simplest way to have a steady
waveform:

```cpp
void setup()
{
    pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
    noInterrupts();
}

void loop()
{
    PORTD |= _BV(PD2);   // PD2 high
    PORTD &= ~_BV(PD2);  // PD2 low
}
```

Without interrupts, you have no timekeeping, no serial communications
and, obviously, no `attachInterrupt()`. Most other Arduino functions
should work.

### Use a hardware timer

This allows you to generate the signal without relying on the CPU. You
can keep interrupts enabled and do other work in the program while the
waveform goes undisturbed. The simplest way to generate such a waveform
is with `analogWrite()`. The resulting frequency is quite low though,
like 0.5 to 1 kHz. If you want 1 MHz, you will have to
configure the timer the hard way. For example:

```cpp
void setup()
{
    DDRD |= _BV(PD3);     // OC2B = PD3 as output
    OCR2A = 15;           // period = 16 clock cycles
    OCR2B = 1;            // high during 2 clock cycles
    TCCR2A = _BV(COM2B1)  // non-inverting PWM
           | _BV(WGM20)   // fast PWM, TOP = OCR2A
           | _BV(WGM21);  // ditto
    TCCR2B = _BV(WGM22)   // ditto
           | _BV(CS20);   // clock at f_CPU
}

void loop() { }
```

The output is on pin PD3 = digital 3. This configuration will disable
`analogWrite()` on pins 3 (PD3) and 11 (PB3).

Comment: What piece of Arduino starts this timer / implements it's interrupt (you should kill it at it's roots? So you can still use other interrupts)? And is there an easy way to see which pieces of code depend on the timed interrupt of Arduino?

Comment: @Paul: It's all in the wiring.c file I already linked to. The interrupt service routine only updates three variables: `timer0_millis`, `timer0_fract` and `timer0_overflow_count`. These are only used inside wring.c. You can see what depends on the interrupt by searching for these variables through the file: only `millis()` and `micros()`. But then `delay()` depends on `micros()`, Stream on `millis()`, and some USB stuff (not on the Uno) on `delay()`.

Comment: Cool, so I could disable this interrupt and still use libraries that use interrupts (such as servo/softserial). Or well, I would have to check if they rely on millis() or micros().

Comment: @Paul: That's correct, but any enabled interrupt would cause the kind of glitch seen here.

Comment: So I added noInterrupts(); in my code and now the waveform is perfect! Thank you very much @Edgar Bonet! And I will try other methods too. There is still so much to learn. I am familiar with Arduino timer but I thought it doesn't affect running program. BTW You all probably know it but these microcontrollers are so cool  :D haha

Answer (score 1):

> I want to produce quick square waveform for testing purposes.
>
> Whole loop cycle take 1 us which mean 16 instructions (62.5 ns per instruction). So I will get 125 ns high and rest of the time low signal.
>   Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

You are assuming that what goes on outside loop() and the call to loop() takes no time at all.

This is what the Arduino core [main()](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/main.cpp#L33) looks like.

```
int main(void)
{
    init();

    initVariant();

#if defined(USBCON)
    USBDevice.attach();
#endif

    setup();

    for (;;) {
        loop();
        if (serialEventRun) serialEventRun();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

There is both the call to loop(), if-branch, and for-branch. This all adds up. On top of this there are a number of Interrupt Service Routines (ISR) such as for the Timer which is used for the micros() and millis() count. These will interleave periodically (as you have observed).

Now the question is how to fix this and I think @Edgar Bonet has done an excellent job with that.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a rough square wave to test and you don't care about the frequency then try this:

```
void setup()
{
   pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() 
{
   digitalWrite(2, true);
   delay(2);
   digitalWrite(2, false);
   delay(2);
}
```

Comment: If you don't care about the frequency, `analogWrite(3, 128);` is simpler.

Comment: @sa_leinad: I care about frequency so I used bitSet/bitClear to make it quicker. Now I have clean 1 Mhz waveform (thanks to Edgar) which I will never achieve with standard digitalWrite.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to reflect this information.